# Change content by pressing button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#contentLeft div').hide();
  $('#contentRight div').hide();
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).show();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
.row {
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-botton: 30px;
}

#contentTab1 {}

#contentTab2 {
  display: none;
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}

#contentTab3 {
  display: none;
  p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: green;
  }
}

#contentRight {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

#contentTabRight2,
#contentTabRight3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="" style="padding-top:12px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn1" data-target="#contentTab1,#contentTabRight1">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn2" data-target="#contentTab2,#contentTabRight2">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn3" data-target="#contentTab3,#contentTabRight3">Button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="contentLeft" class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="contentTab1">
      <h2>Some Title 1</h2>
      <p>This is the content for pressing button 1. Venenatis iaculis tempor suspendisse condimentum egestas a a nulla odio eu parturient nibh parturient sem risus aliquam feugiat a enim nam ullamcorper suspendisse cum ullamcorper ac vestibulum adipiscing.
        Vestibulum dignissim vivamus nec iaculis vestibulum parturient conubia et ac scelerisque arcu litora mus ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTab2">
      <h2>Some Title 2</h2>
      <p>
        Posuere posuere vestibulum vestibulum lobortis a venenatis libero tempor fermentum vestibulum purus suspendisse suspendisse a quam magnis eleifend magnis taciti parturient sit mi mi.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTab3">
      <h2>Some Title 3</h2>
      <p>
        Nisl eu mus nec a molestie nulla molestie leo urna vestibulum maecenas a vestibulum et velit dis. Cum a convallis sagittis magnis ullamcorper a bibendum a quis lobortis vitae lacinia vel sem ultricies interdum convallis tincidunt ac arcu nam. Id vivamus
        mi dapibus ultricies nisi consectetur congue felis a nullam a condimentum lacinia a est imperdiet.
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="contentRight" class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="contentTabRight1">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 1
      </h3>
      <p>
        Nascetur nec ultrices condimentum torquent.
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech/sepia" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="contentTabRight2">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 2
      </h3>
      <p>
        some content paragraph goes here...
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="contentTabRight3">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 3
      </h3>
      <p>
        Integer a a dictum diam dictumst magnis a vestibulum tellus convallis leo in parturient sodales purus himenaeos egestas.Nibh orci dui fames.
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/any/grayscale" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm having an issue with changing content within a Div using jQuery. I have a page with 3 buttons and I need the content to update, in 2 places (left column and right column) on the screen, when a new button is pressed. I have it to work with the 1st Div to update, but I can't get the 2nd Div to update. Any suggestion or help is very much appreciated.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#contentLeft div').hide();
  var target = '#' + $(this).data('target');
  $(target).show();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

.row {
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-botton: 30px;
}

#contentTab1 {
  
}

#contentTab2 {
  display:none;
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}

#contentTab3 {
  display:none;
  p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: green;
  }
}

#contentRight {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="" style="padding-top:12px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn1" data-target="contentTab1,contentTabRight1">Button 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn2" data-target="contentTab2,contentTabRight2">Button 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn3" data-target="contentTab3,contentTabRight3">Button 3</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="contentLeft" class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="contentTab1">
      <h2>Some Title 1</h2>
      <p>This is the content for pressing button 1. Venenatis iaculis tempor suspendisse condimentum egestas a a nulla odio eu parturient nibh parturient sem risus aliquam feugiat a enim nam ullamcorper suspendisse cum ullamcorper ac vestibulum adipiscing. Vestibulum dignissim vivamus nec iaculis vestibulum parturient conubia et ac scelerisque arcu litora mus ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTab2">
      <h2>Some Title 2</h2>
      <p>
      Posuere posuere vestibulum vestibulum lobortis a venenatis libero tempor fermentum vestibulum purus suspendisse suspendisse a quam magnis eleifend magnis taciti parturient sit mi mi.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTab3">
      <h2>Some Title 3</h2>
      <p>
      Nisl eu mus nec a molestie nulla molestie leo urna vestibulum maecenas a vestibulum et velit dis. Cum a convallis sagittis magnis ullamcorper a bibendum a quis lobortis vitae lacinia vel sem ultricies interdum convallis tincidunt ac arcu nam. Id vivamus mi dapibus ultricies nisi consectetur congue felis a nullam a condimentum lacinia a est imperdiet.
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="contentRight" class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="contentTabRight1">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 1
      </h3>
      <p>
      Nascetur nec ultrices condimentum torquent.
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech/sepia" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="contentTabRight2">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 2
      </h3>
      <p>
        some content paragraph goes here...
      </p>
      <img
      src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="contentTabRight3">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 3
      </h3>
      <p>
        Integer a a dictum diam dictumst magnis a vestibulum tellus convallis leo in parturient sodales purus himenaeos egestas.Nibh orci dui fames.
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/any/grayscale" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change your `data-target` values to be selectors. IOW, `data-target="#contentTab2,#contentTabRight2"`, then change your line to `var target = $(this).data('target');`, without the leading '#'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are storing the ID references as a comma-separated string in the `data-target` attribute, and when constructing a selector from said string you are only appending a `#` to the start, i.e.:

`contentTab1,contentTabRight1`

...will give you:

`#contentTab1,contentTabRight1`, the latter of which is not a valid CSS selector. What you want is to split the string by the `,` separator, and then append `#` to each of them. An example:

```
var target = $(this).data('target').split(',').map(function(t) {
    return '#' + t;
}).join(',');
$(target).show();
```

Alternatively, you simply update the hardcoded values in `data-target` to use the correct selector format to begin with, e.g. `#contentTab1,#contentTabRight1`, then you don't need to change your JS logic at all.

The example below refers to my first solution:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#contentLeft div').hide();
  var target = $(this).data('target').split(',').map(function(t) {
    return '#' + t;
  }).join(',');
  $(target).show();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

.row {
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-botton: 30px;
}

#contentTab1 {
  
}

#contentTab2 {
  display:none;
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}

#contentTab3 {
  display:none;
  p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: green;
  }
}

#contentRight {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

#contentTabRight2, #contentTabRight3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="" style="padding-top:12px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn1" data-target="contentTab1,contentTabRight1">Button 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn2" data-target="contentTab2,contentTabRight2">Button 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn3" data-target="contentTab3,contentTabRight3">Button 3</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="contentLeft" class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="contentTab1">
      <h2>Some Title 1</h2>
      <p>This is the content for pressing button 1. Venenatis iaculis tempor suspendisse condimentum egestas a a nulla odio eu parturient nibh parturient sem risus aliquam feugiat a enim nam ullamcorper suspendisse cum ullamcorper ac vestibulum adipiscing. Vestibulum dignissim vivamus nec iaculis vestibulum parturient conubia et ac scelerisque arcu litora mus ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTab2">
      <h2>Some Title 2</h2>
      <p>
      Posuere posuere vestibulum vestibulum lobortis a venenatis libero tempor fermentum vestibulum purus suspendisse suspendisse a quam magnis eleifend magnis taciti parturient sit mi mi.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTab3">
      <h2>Some Title 3</h2>
      <p>
      Nisl eu mus nec a molestie nulla molestie leo urna vestibulum maecenas a vestibulum et velit dis. Cum a convallis sagittis magnis ullamcorper a bibendum a quis lobortis vitae lacinia vel sem ultricies interdum convallis tincidunt ac arcu nam. Id vivamus mi dapibus ultricies nisi consectetur congue felis a nullam a condimentum lacinia a est imperdiet.
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="contentRight" class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="contentTabRight1">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 1
      </h3>
      <p>
      Nascetur nec ultrices condimentum torquent.
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech/sepia" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="contentTabRight2">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 2
      </h3>
      <p>
        some content paragraph goes here...
      </p>
      <img
      src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="contentTabRight3">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 3
      </h3>
      <p>
        Integer a a dictum diam dictumst magnis a vestibulum tellus convallis leo in parturient sodales purus himenaeos egestas.Nibh orci dui fames.
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/any/grayscale" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I was able to resolve my issue with you 2nd suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you'll get the idea.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
   $('#contentLeft div').hide();
   $('#contentRight div').hide();
   var target = '#' + $(this).data('target')
   target = target.split(',');
   $(target[0]).show();
   $('#' + target[1]).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to log what there is inside target variable?

I think that it will be solved to a no sense directive:

```
'#contentTab1,contentTabRight1'
```

I know that it'll be a ugly solution but could work:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#contentLeft div').hide();
  var ids = $(this).data('target').split(',');
  ids.each(function(i, data){
    $('#' + data).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out my issue with a few of the suggestions. Thanks a lot for all of the help!

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#contentLeft div').hide();
  $('#contentRight div').hide();
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).show();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
.row {
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-botton: 30px;
}

#contentTab1 {}

#contentTab2 {
  display: none;
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}

#contentTab3 {
  display: none;
  p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: green;
  }
}

#contentRight {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

#contentTabRight2,
#contentTabRight3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="" style="padding-top:12px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn1" data-target="#contentTab1,#contentTabRight1">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn2" data-target="#contentTab2,#contentTabRight2">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Btn3" data-target="#contentTab3,#contentTabRight3">Button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="contentLeft" class="col-sm-4">
    <div id="contentTab1">
      <h2>Some Title 1</h2>
      <p>This is the content for pressing button 1. Venenatis iaculis tempor suspendisse condimentum egestas a a nulla odio eu parturient nibh parturient sem risus aliquam feugiat a enim nam ullamcorper suspendisse cum ullamcorper ac vestibulum adipiscing.
        Vestibulum dignissim vivamus nec iaculis vestibulum parturient conubia et ac scelerisque arcu litora mus ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTab2">
      <h2>Some Title 2</h2>
      <p>
        Posuere posuere vestibulum vestibulum lobortis a venenatis libero tempor fermentum vestibulum purus suspendisse suspendisse a quam magnis eleifend magnis taciti parturient sit mi mi.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentTab3">
      <h2>Some Title 3</h2>
      <p>
        Nisl eu mus nec a molestie nulla molestie leo urna vestibulum maecenas a vestibulum et velit dis. Cum a convallis sagittis magnis ullamcorper a bibendum a quis lobortis vitae lacinia vel sem ultricies interdum convallis tincidunt ac arcu nam. Id vivamus
        mi dapibus ultricies nisi consectetur congue felis a nullam a condimentum lacinia a est imperdiet.
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="contentRight" class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="contentTabRight1">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 1
      </h3>
      <p>
        Nascetur nec ultrices condimentum torquent.
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech/sepia" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="contentTabRight2">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 2
      </h3>
      <p>
        some content paragraph goes here...
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/tech" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="contentTabRight3">
      <h3>
        Right Side Content Title 3
      </h3>
      <p>
        Integer a a dictum diam dictumst magnis a vestibulum tellus convallis leo in parturient sodales purus himenaeos egestas.Nibh orci dui fames.
      </p>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/100/any/grayscale" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```